# There was no endpoint listening at URL that could accept the message?

Tags: wcf

I have got this issue on IIS but when I run it on my machine it works fine. Please see my web.config below. I am stuck in this situation for a long time please help me out in order to sort out the problem.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <configuration>
    <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5.1" tempDirectory="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\five9" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>`enter code here`
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WsAdminBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
                    </security>

                    <!-- <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="UserName" />
                    </security> -->
                </binding>
                <binding name="WsAdminBinding1" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://api.five9.com/wsadmin/v3/AdminWebService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WsAdminBinding" contract="Five9API_v3.WsAdmin" name="WsAdminPort" />
        </client>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Metadata">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="getUserInfo.aspx" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer></configuration>
```

Passing username and password in a header in order to access this webservice and i can achieve in following way and it works fine on my machine but create issue on server.

```
var client = new Five9API_v3.WsAdminClient();

                var loginCredentials = new ClientCredentials();

                loginCredentials.UserName.UserName = username;
                loginCredentials.UserName.Password = password;

                client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = username;
                client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;

                client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Remove(client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Find<ClientCredentials>());
                client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(loginCredentials);
```

Comment: Is your firewall configured to allow that traffic?

Comment: Yeah I think so because when i use the service url https://api.five9.com/wsadmin/v3/AdminWebService in webpage it appears correctly.

Comment: Open the URL in your browser and see what errors you get there.

Comment: Now Url is opening fine actually we need to send user name and password in a header in order to access this web service and I can handle it in following way.

Comment: Any Solution ? or any thoughts

Comment: I got 500 - Internal Server Error issue now